# How to Align memory between JNA and C

Tags: c, linux, jna, file-read

I need to provide a direct read operation with O_DIRECT flag in linux environment.
The current read operantion seems to fail because buffer memory is not aligned.
How can I align buffer memory?

I have tried this:

```
Native.getLibraryOptions(Linux_C_lib_DirectMapping.class).put(Library.OPTION_STRUCTURE_ALIGNMENT, Structure.ALIGN_DEFAULT);
```

But the read process fails again.

This is the test code:

```
int ha = libC.open("/var/test/writetest", 0x1000 | 0x100000 | 0x4000 | 0x80);
if(ha<0){
    System.out.println("Error opening file");
    return;
}else{
    byte[] bb=new byte[512];
    int readed=libC.read(ha, bb, bb.length);
    System.out.println("lasterr:" +Native.getLastError());
    System.out.println("Read size:" +readed);
    System.out.println(new String(bb));
    libC.close(ha);
}
```

This is the current output:

```
lasterr:22
Readeed:-1
```

This is the c lib JNA mapping:

```
package test;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;

public class Linux_C_lib_DirectMapping implements Linux_C_lib {

    native public int open(String path, int flags);

    native public int close(int fd);

    native public int read(int fd, byte[] buffer, int count);


    static {
        try {
            Native.register("c");
            Native.getLibraryOptions(Linux_C_lib_DirectMapping.class).put(Library.OPTION_STRUCTURE_ALIGNMENT, Structure.ALIGN_DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and this one:

```
package test;

public interface Linux_C_lib extends com.sun.jna.Library {

    public int open(String path, int flags);

    public int close(int fd);

    public int read(int fd, byte[] buffer, int count);

}
```

Comment: Generally you can''t. While not technically guaranteed, you're likely to get page alignment on direct byte buffers, and generally you can instead allocate a larger buffer and then align within that region

Answer (score 0):

This guy has found a solution!
http://www.nicecode.eu/java-streams-for-direct-io/

Take a loot at JNAInputStream class.

```
PointerByReference pntByRef = new PointerByReference();
posix_memalign(pntByRef, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
bufPnt = pntByRef.getValue();       
buffer = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
```